# xslt distribute list elements to nodes

Tags: list, xslt, distribute

I would like to transform an xml with the following structure

```
<R>
    <S>
            <SN>S00</SN>
            <SN>S01</SN>
            <SN>S02</SN>
    </S>
    <L>
        <ID>100</ID>
        <Q>1</Q>
    </L>
    <L>
        <ID>200</ID>
        <Q>2</Q>
    </L>
</R>
```

To this:

```
<R>
    <L>
        <ID>100</ID>
        <Q>1</Q>
        <S>
            <SN>S00</SN>
        </S>
    </L>
    <L>
        <ID>200</ID>
        <Q>2</Q>
        <S>
            <SN>S01</SN>
            <SN>S02</SN>
        </S>    
    </L>
</R>
```

Explanation: The task is to distribute the elements of the S element to the L elements. The value of Q in the respective L elements controls how many elements from S should be moved to the L element. The order of the S elements does not matter.

Think of a practical case like this: There is a number (Q) of items from a production batch (ID) and we want to stick a badge with a serial number (SN) to each individual item. The result of the transformation says: "glue the badge with serial number S00 to the one item from batch 100 and the serial numbers S01 and S02 to the two items from batch 200."

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Bernhard! What have you tried? Where is the problem? Your post does not contain a question/problem except "please do it for me" which is not what SO is for...so please edit the question to show the problematic code

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I can only use XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sibling recursion on the `L` elements, passing on the remaining `S` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="R">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="sn" select="S/SN"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="L[1]">
                <xsl:with-param name="sn" select="$sn"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="L">
        <xsl:param name="sn"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            <S>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$sn[position() &lt;= current()/Q]"/>
            </S>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::L[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="sn" select="$sn[position() > current()/Q]"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Q">
    <xsl:variable name="start" select="sum(../preceding-sibling::L/Q)" />
    <xsl:variable name="end" select="$start + ." />
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <S>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../../S/SN[$start &lt; position() and position() &lt;= $end]"/>
    </S>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="S"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem with this approach that it's not very efficient: each `L` node calculates the sum of `Q` values of all its preceding sibling instead of just adding its value to  an accumulated sum.

If your input has a large number of nodes, consider a recursive approach - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/R">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="gen">
            <xsl:with-param name="batches" select="L"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="labels" select="S/SN"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="gen">
    <xsl:param name="batches" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="labels" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:variable name="batch" select="$batches[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="q" select="$batch/Q" />
    <xsl:if test="$batches">
        <L>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$batch/ID | $q"/>
            <S>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$labels[position() &lt;= $q]"/>
            </S>  
        </L>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="gen">
            <xsl:with-param name="batches" select="$batches[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="labels" select="$labels[position() > $q]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have considered the recursive approach, but I couldn't get it working yet.